# Reading a register while disabling interrupts

Tags: c++, interrupt, avr

I want to read a timer register while disabling interrupts. One way of doing it, is the following:

```
int read()
{
    int res;

    {// for scope of Interrupt_locks
        Interrupt_locks lock; // the constructor disable interrupts
        res = my_register;
     } // destructor of Interrupt_locks enables interrupts

    return res;
}
```

But it's cleaner to do it this way:

```
int read()
{
   Interrupt_locks lock;
   return my_register;
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure when is called the destructor of `Interrupt_lock`.

So my question is: when is the destructor of `Interrupt_locks` called? Before or afther the return statement?

Comment: It happens after the thing being returned is calculated, but before the return actually happens. The two versions you posted are equivalent.

Comment: Does the first variant work (unrelated to the lock)? I would assume that res is declared only within the scope of the inner braces?

Comment: @Sebastian, you are right.  I didn't copy my code directly, so I made a mistake. Of course, you have to declare `res` outside. I edit it now. Thanks.

Comment: It happens when it goes out of scope.. That means after the return, because the return is still inside of scope.